# How to get current login user

Tags: outlook, exchangewebservices

I want to get current login user via EWS.                                    I search some document, but I don’t find a method to get current user. I need your help. Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dmitry said, you could use ResolveName. For example:

```
NameResolutionCollection ncCol = service.ResolveName("user@domain.com",ResolveNameSearchLocation.DirectoryOnly,true);
    Console.WriteLine(ncCol[0].Contact.DisplayName);
```

You could also use ConverId with a generic address to get the current user’s own email. For example:

```
Folder Inbox = Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
        AlternateId aiAlternateid = new AlternateId(IdFormat.EwsId, Inbox.Id.UniqueId, "mailbox@domain.com");
        AlternateIdBase aiResponse = service.ConvertId(aiAlternateid, IdFormat.EwsId);
        Console.WriteLine(((AlternateId)aiResponse).Mailbox);
```

AutoDiscover will also return the PrimarySMTP address of a Mailbox as you do a POX based discovery.

Answer (score 1):

Use [ResolveName EWS operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/resolvenames-operation) - you will only need the user's SMTP address.